# Get current item from custom editor Sitecore 6.5

Tags: .net, editor, sitecore

I have trouble with get current item where I define custom editor. 
I need to get Id of current page (article) but `Sitecore.Context.Item` return to me null.
How get id from current item?

**UPD:**
Editor aspx file is test for work

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Comments" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></b>
        <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%></p>         
    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <SeparatorTemplate><hr /></SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

cs (Page_Load):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Request.QueryString["id"]);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"..."))
    {
        var query = "SELECT Name, Text from dbo.Comments " +
            "WHERE Article = @CurrentItemId";
        var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentItemId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = currentItem.ID.ToGuid();
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            var list = new List<Comment>();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Comment(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString()));
            }

            Comments.DataSource = list;
            Comments.DataBind();

            reader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your custom editor exactly?

Comment: Where is the code being run from?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the current item ID and current language from the querysting

```
// get the current Item and language
string itemID = Request.QueryString["id"];
Language language = LanguageManager.GetLanguage(Request.QueryString["la"]);

if (language != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemID))
{
    Database masterDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    CurrentItem = masterDB.GetItem(itemID, language);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find id of this item. You can get item_id from QueryStrings of tour Request:
`Request.QueryString["id"]`.

I had not enough to find the answer becouse id of item from QueryStrings get in format `{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}`